# Simple hash method in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to implement a simple hash method in C++ that takes a character array of max length 1024 and turns it into an array of max length 256. I'm getting incorrect values and I'm not sure why.

Test input: This is a test

Test output: fWhis is▒~▒▒▒▒t

Expected output: This is a test

I've written the same method in java and it's working good.

```
void hash(char* message, char* output)
{
    //Hash
    int i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(message)-1){
        output[i % N] += message[i++];
    }
    output[N-1] = '\0';
 }
```

Method Called:

```
char bufferMes[1024];
char bufferHash[256];

printf("Please enter the message: ");
fgets(bufferMes, 1023, stdin);

hash(bufferMes, bufferHash);
```

I'm thinking that I have junk values in my output array when I initialize it, so I tried creating a helper method clear() to initialize every value in the output array, but that just gave me weird values again.

Comment: You want the output to be the same as the input?

Comment: In this test case, it should be because the message isn't greater than 256 characters. Essentially what I want is if the first character is a and the 256th character is b then the new first char would be b. In other words, every 256 characters it starts writing over itself.

Comment: You aren't properly null terminating `output` when the amount of data in it is less that `N` (I assume that `N` is 256?). Also this line `output[i % N] += message[i++];` exhibits undefined behavior.  Increment `i` on a separate line.

Comment: The buffer is also not zero-initialized which is another source of undefined behavior. And please don't call `strlen` repetitively in the loop condition. As a matter of fact, you don't need it at all here.

Comment: Thanks all! Incrementing i on the next line and zero-initializing the arrays fixed the problems. I've also removed the calls to strlen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code:

- This is C++ written like C. You'll be better off in the long run learning to use `string`.
- We're supposed to imagine what `N` is. I'm assuming it's 256. You'll get better help from SO if you provide small, complete, runnable code.
- You should be passing the length of the output as a parameter, not assuming a global definition. This way the function stands alone, which is a best practice.
- The `while` condition calls `strlen()` in every iteration. `strlen()`'s run time is O(`n`) for a string of length `n`. You've turned a loop that ought to be O(`n`) into one that's O(`n`^2).
- Use of `while` here is not a best practice. Use `for`.
- You never initialize the array `output`.
- You're computing a result with `N` characters, then overwriting the `N`th with zero.  The buffer `output` must be of length `N`+1 so there's space to write the terminating null character after the `N` output characters.
- `int` is a buggy way to index an array. You should really use `size_t`.
- In the calling code, you've forgotten to allow an extra character for null termination. Your code will read a max of only 1023 characters, not 1024. Ditto for the hash.

Cleaning all of this up, you'll get something like:

```
void hash(char* message, char* hash_buf, size_t hash_buf_size)
{
  // Zero the output buffer, including the terminal null character.
  memset(hash_buf, '\0', hash_buf_size);
  size_t len = strlen(message);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    hash_buf[i % (hash_buf_size - 1)] += message[i];
}
```

Then to call this:

```
char message[1025], hash[257];

fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
hash(message, hash, sizeof hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what has been mentioned in the comments.

- Accessing the variable `i` twice in the same statement while modifying it is undefined behavior.
- An uninitialized buffer is not zero-initialized. Reading from it (also implicitly via `+=`) is undefined behavior.
- Calling `strlen` in each iteration of the loop is wasteful.
- The NUL termination of the output buffer is suspicious. Since adding characters together isn't guaranteed to give any printable characters anyway, NUL termination is probably not a good idea to begin with.
- Since the addition might yield a larger value than a `char` can hold, you should use `unsigned char` because signed overflow is undefined behavior and `char` may either be `signed` or `unsigned`.
- `fgets` already subtracts the space for the terminating NUL byte from the buffer size so you can pass the actual array size to it.
- `N` is a magic number, it should be an input parameter to `hash`.

Putting it all together, your code might look something like this. Note that while you have tagged your question as “C++”, the code doesn't use a single C++ feature so I'm showing C99 code here. In C++, you would probably prefer using `std::string`s or – even better – iterators over raw pointer arrays.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void
hash(const char * message, unsigned char *const output, const size_t n)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  memset(output, 0, n);
  while (*message != '\0')
    output[i++ % n] += *message++;
}

int
main()
{
  char message[1024];
  unsigned char output[256];
  printf("Please enter the message: ");
  fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
  hash(message, output, sizeof(output));
  fwrite(output, sizeof(output), 1, stdout);
  fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Comment: "Accessing the variable i twice in the same statement while modifying it is undefined behavior." It is my understanding that in C++17 this is no longer the case. The order of execution is now well defined.